# Can I avoid placing the content of a TreeViewItem in the top-left corner of my WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window that has some ListViews inside a TreeView. Whenever the content of the TreeViewItem gets too high and/ or too wide the content gets placed on the top-left corner of the window (see images) as soon as I click on a free spot "inside" the TreeViewItem.
Is there any possibility/ property to avoid this? I want to leave the choice where to scroll to to the user and don't want to interupt his reading when he accidentally clicks somewhere.

Simplified Example:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="400">

<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Some Headline" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Some Text" IsExpanded="True">
            <TextBlock Width="400" Height="150" Background="PaleGreen"> Some Text in a Block</TextBlock>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem> 
</TreeView>
```

Pictures:
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcjJ.png)
[How I expect it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt6BP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Some Headline" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Some Text" IsExpanded="True">
                <TextBlock Width="400" Height="150" Background="PaleGreen"> Some Text in a Block</TextBlock>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Sven.